# 431 (Request Header Fields Too Large) (ReactJS/ Flask)

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, flask, fetch

I'm getting a **431 error** on a simple fetch post, specifically:

> net::ERR_ABORTED 431 (Request Header Fields Too Large)

Proxy set to: "proxy": "http://0.0.0.0:3000" (on reactjs)

```
fetch("/process_image", {
  method:"POST",
  cache: "no-store",
  headers:{
      "content_type":"application/json",
  },
  body:JSON.stringify("testing")
  }
).then(response => {

  //return response.json()
})
.then(json => {

//this.setState({playerName: json[0]})
});
```

I have tried to clear the **cache** and **cookies** on my browser based on the solutions similar to my problem but nothing is helping, and I wouldn't think this would cause an issue since all I'm passing is a *small text*.

I have also tried to replicate my solution using `.net` core, and I am able to post data with no issues, but using *.net* core does not fit in my scope. (I'm learning how to use flask)

I'm passing the data to a `.py` file:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS
import Image, io, base64
import numpy as np
from keras import models

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return "Hello, Flask!"

@app.route("/process_image", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def process_image():
    data_uri = request.json()
    print("hello:    ", data_uri)
```

Any ideas what could be causing the problem?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by this, but when i run "npm start" the web site is running on '(localhost: 3000)', is this what you mean?

Comment: Are you using flask's built-in dev server to run your flask application? Sometimes, server configurations might lead to this error.

Comment: I did that and is says my local host is now 5000 i applied the changes to the proxy and not i am getting a 500 error and TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable